# How to use predicate to get ordered list of Core Data NSSet relationship?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have an instance of the Department entity, which in turn has a relationship to the Employee entity via the 'employees' to-many relationship.

How would I construct my NSPredicate to return an array of employees within the specific department, in employeeNumber order, from this Department instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A predicate's purpose is to *filter* items, not to sort them. Use your fetch request's `sortDescriptors` property to determine how the results are sorted.

Alternatively, if you're accessing the relationship via the object's properties, use the `NSSet` method `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` to create a sorted array from the set of objects.